# html css external style sheet does not work

Tags: html, css

I am a newcomer to html and web development.
Recently I want to create my website and on one of the pages I want it have a form.
I use [pageclip](https://pageclip.co) and followed instructions from it.
The site is on: [wcyat.me/pageclip](https://wcyat.me/pageclip)
code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <link href="https://s.pageclip.co/v1/pageclip.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="https://send.pageclip.co/p4eaPA68eOwq8IiuoAfyxqPcXirFGmfr/contact-form" class="pageclip-form" method="post">
  <!-- Replace these inputs with your own. Make sure they have a "name" attribute! -->

  <!-- It looks like you are creating a contact form. These email and subject fields are special -->
  <!-- See https://pageclip.co/docs#special-fields for more info -->
      <input type="email" name="email" value="roscoe@example.com" />
      <input type="text" name="subject" value="A contact subject" />

  <!-- This button will have a loading spinner. Keep the inner span for best results. -->
      <button type="submit" class="pageclip-form__submit">
          <span>Send</span>
      </button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://s.pageclip.co/v1/pageclip.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
  <footer class="site-footer">
      <center>
          <div id="footer">
            <a href="https://simpleanalytics.com/?utm_source=wcyat.me&utm_content=badge" referrerpolicy="origin" target="_blank"><img src="https://simpleanalyticsbadge.com/wcyat.me" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" crossorigin="anonymous" /></a>
            <a href="https://github.com/wcyat"><img alt="github" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wcyat/wcyat.github.io/main/images/GitHub-Mark.png"width=50" height="46.06"></a>
            <a href="https://t.me/abc64899"><img alt="telegram" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wcyat/wcyat.github.io/main/images/Logo.svg"width=40" height=40"></a>
          </div>
      </center>
  </footer>
</html>
```

I don't know whether it's my problem or not because I don't really know a lot about web development.

Comment: Why are you saying its not working? looks fine to me, that CSS file doesnt have much in it but it seems to be applied just fine to the page.

Comment: In your HTML, you must surround attribute values with quotes and you must separate your attributes. Note that you have markup like: `width=50" height="46.06"></a>
            <a href="https://t.me/abc64899"><img alt="telegram" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wcyat/wcyat.github.io/main/images/Logo.svg"width=40" height=40"` which should be: `width="50" height="46.06"></a>
            <a href="https://t.me/abc64899"><img alt="telegram" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wcyat/wcyat.github.io/main/images/Logo.svg" width="40" height="40"`

Comment: @Julien because it should be like this: https://pageclip.co/docs#website-integration